# Vert.x, RoutingContext can't receive json array

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have a problem with receiving json array.

Sending JSON is:

```
[
     {
        "name": "Account 3",
        "type": 2,
        "active": true
     },
     {
         "name": "Account 4",
         "type": 1,
         "active": true
     },
     {
         "name": "Account 5",
         "type": 0,
         "active": true
     }
]
```

The error is:

```
Mar 31, 2018 6:28:37 PM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token
```

TenantSecurity class:

```
class TenantSwitcherHandler(val vertx: Vertx) {
fun switchTenant(routingContext: RoutingContext) {
    val tenantId: String? = routingContext.request().headers().get(CommonConstants.HEADER_TENANT)
    if (tenantId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.code()).end(ErrorMessages.CANT_FIND_X_TENANT_ID_HEADER.value())
        return
    } else {
        vertx.eventBus().send(CommonConstants.SWITCH_TENANT, tenantId)
        routingContext.next()
    }
}
}
```

Error occurs while executing routingContext.next()...
how can I fix the problem?

P.S.: TenantSwitcherHandler class registered as Security handler, which switches pointer to database according to X-TENANT-ID header value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to the code you posted, actually, but to the next route you have.
Array you send is not a valid JSON Object.
You can either:

1. Send it wrapped from your client: `{"array":[...]}`
2. Use `getBodyAsJsonArray` instead

Here's some code you can play with:
final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

```
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.post("/").handler(c -> {
            JsonObject json = c.getBodyAsJson();
            // If you want to read JSON array, use this
            // JsonArray jsonArray = c.getBodyAsJsonArray();

            c.response().end(json.toString());
        }
    );
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8443);


    System.out.println("Server started");
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

    // This will succeed
    client.request(HttpMethod.POST, 8443, "localhost", "/").
            sendBuffer(Buffer.buffer("{}"), h -> {
                System.out.println(h.result().bodyAsString());
            });

    // This will fail
    client.request(HttpMethod.POST, 8443, "localhost", "/").
            sendBuffer(Buffer.buffer("[]"), h -> {
                System.out.println(h.result().bodyAsString());
    });
```

Comment: The OP could just get body as a `Buffer` and deserialize it the way he likes using any sort of specifically configured JSON deserializer

Comment: Thanx, for your reply. I fixed the problem, sending wrapped array